# Interval Arithmetic when calculating eigenvectors

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, eigenvalues, intervals

Consider the following matrix with entries being intervals

```
A={{Interval[{-1.00034, -1.00031}], 
  Interval[{0.00980599, 
    0.00982034}]}, {Interval[{-0.0262465, -0.0262241}], 
  Interval[{-0.207671, -0.207659}]}}
```

I ask Mathematica to calculate the normalized leading eigenvector which gives:

```
Normalize[Eigenvectors[A][[1]]]
{Interval[{0.741586, 1.34695}], Interval[{0.0281967, 0.0379947}]}
```

The error worried me, it seems way too big. So I tried just using the formula for an eigenvector as this is just the $2\times 2$ case.

```
Normalize[{(A)[[1]][[2]], 
  Eigenvalues[
    A][[1]] - (A)[[1]][[1]]}]
{Interval[{0.997819, 1.00106}], Interval[{0.0281876, 0.038007}]}
```

This gives much better estimates, what is going on? Mathematica calculates eigenvectors in a weird way (for a general size) and hence loses a lot of precision?

Comment: What are `A` and `B`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that multiple `Interval`s in the same expression are treated as independent, even if they should represent the same quantity.

As a simple example, consider

```
#^2 - #*# &[Interval[{0, 1}]]
(* Interval[{-1, 1}] *)
```

Of course, the correct value of applying this function is zero

```
#^2 - #*# &[x]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: I am surprised this causes so much error but makes sense. I assumed Interval Arithmetic was much smarter than that ;/